# Android Layout issues.. Not sure how to debug

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, android-layout, xamarin.android

**UPDATE____**

Logcat output http://pastie.org/2039452

My application is stopping in the debugger, and then crashing on this line, but it is strange because it has no error information just a green arrow like so...

Any insight on what this arrow means in general would be appreciated...

[image]

Here is LayoutStudentList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/studentHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/StudentListHeader"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/studentSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/studentHeader"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:hint="@string/StudentFilterPlaceholder"
    />
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/studentListView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/studentSearch"
      android:padding="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is almost definitely in my XML somewhere, as when I replace the layout contents with a single textview and set the text it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the studentSearch EditText element in your layout file didn't specify a `layout_height` attribute. Once you add that in the problem should go away (I verified this locally as well). The error message and accompanying stacktrace would also be visible via the [ADB logcat output](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat):

```
I/dalvikvm( 2083): Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;: Binary XML file line #14: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

Comment: Fixed that. and still does the same thing, logcat output here --> http://pastie.org/2039452

Comment: There's not too much there, but it looks like the debugger had some trouble starting up. I'd suggest trying a clean build and launching again to see if it helps at all. Killing adb.exe instances from Task Manager might help too.

Comment: One other thing worth mentioning is that you might want to try running the app without debugging. The debugger in Mono For Android can be painfully slow at times, so you'll get much better performance by not using it when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

What does 'hanging' mean?  Like, stopped in the debugger?  Crashing?

Shouldn't that be `setContentView()`, not Set with a capital S?  Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Stopping in the debugger, freezing Visual Studio, and then crashing on my dev device.  made more specific in the Original question.  Actually `SetContentView()` is capitalized in C#, I'm using Mono for Android.

Comment: Any stack trace in logcat on the device?  I don't use VS but when I debug in Eclipse and an exception is thrown it usually breaks into the debugger prior to the exception.

Comment: He is using MonoDroid, so on .Net and Visual Studio, not Java.

Comment: `adb logcat` in a command window should fetch the trace for you.